# Browser Timeout When Saving Attribute with Large Amount of Data

Tags: javascript, browser

Our store has thousands of color options and any time we try to make an edit and save, the browser times out and forces a "kill page".

I have uploaded the files for this extension here: https://github.com/Jarlssen/Jarlssen_FasterAttributeOptionEdit

I am still not having any success, so I'm wondering if I installed incorrectly, or if I have to take further action once the extension is installed? Does this extension continually run as long as it's uploaded?

Comment: The code should be posted **here**.

Comment: If you were linking somewhere, it didn't work?

Comment: Pointy means that you should put the code directly in your question. Or at least the relevant part of your code.

Comment: There are 5 files full of code.... not sure if I'm following here...

Comment: So you want us to peruse 5 separate files "full" of code trying to figure out what might possibly be going wrong? Have you tried creating a [short, self-contained example](http://sscce.org/) of the problem?

Comment: Disclaimer: I am not a developer, so this type of thing is somewhat foreign to me.

Comment: I'm basing this question off of this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634309/problems-saving-large-number-of-attribute-option-labels-in-magento

Based off this thread, it seems that the issue is solved simply by installing the extension... Am I wrong?

Comment: make the request data smaller or give heartbeats from the server...

Comment: I wish I knew what that means.. I guess I'm flat out screwed here. :(

Comment: _Disclaimer: I am not a developer_ Most likely you cannot get help here. Contact the developer on GitHub. Go to the extension page and open New Issue

Comment: Thanks everyone and sorry to be a pain. I just submitted to the developer.